# How can I show invisibles in Brackets?

Tags: brackets

Is there a way to show the (normally invisble) formatting characters in Adobe Brackets? Things like spaces, tabs, and new lines are what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know if you already found the solution but search for a extension called "Show Whitespace", it tries to copy the whitespace highlighting sublimetext has and is doing a pretty good job at it!

https://github.com/DennisKehrig/brackets-show-whitespace

Comment: so far that's still the only way: with extensions.

Comment: doesn't show newlines!